Test for reading InfluxDB data using Springboot
I made CRUD method for InfluxDBClient(v2) but i failed with 401 unauthorization error.
I checked with my token, url, bucket name and organization several times.
Below message is my error result.
Is there any configuration to check?
If you need my extra code please give me any comment.
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class InfluxServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    InfluxDBClient influxDBClient;

    @Autowired
    InfluxService influxService;

    @Autowired
    private InfluxController influxController;

    @Test
    public void readData() {
        LocalDateTime testDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        ElectricityData electricityData = influxController.getElectricityData(testDateTime);
        assertThat(electricityData).isNotNull();

    }

}

2024-10-14T17:25:24.522+09:00  INFO 22804 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
InfluxDBClient created with URL: class Ready {
    status: ready
    started: 2024-10-14T03:00:46.907254903Z
    up: 5h6m25.201172097s
}
2024-10-14T17:25:25.194+09:00  WARN 22804 --- [    Test worker] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-10-14T17:25:25.555+09:00  INFO 22804 --- [    Test worker] o.atg.bems.connection.InfluxServiceTest  : Started InfluxServiceTest in 4.125 seconds (process running for 5.214)
Hibernate: 
    select
        ed1_0.Building,
        ed1_0.DateTime,
        ed1_0.DataValue 
    from
        Tech_All_KWH ed1_0
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\Users\ATG\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.19\154da3a65b4f4a909d3e5bdec55d1b2b4cbb6ce1\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.19.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
2024-10-14T17:25:30.432+09:00  INFO 22804 --- [    Test worker] o.atg.bems.controller.InfluxController   : Fetching electricity data at time: 2024-10-14T17:25:30.431750600
2024-10-14T17:25:30.444+09:00  WARN 22804 --- [    Test worker] c.i.client.internal.InfluxDBClientImpl   : Authorization interception failed. Already signed out.

HTTP status code: 401; Message: unauthorized access
com.influxdb.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: HTTP status code: 401; Message: unauthorized access
    at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractRestClient.responseToError(AbstractRestClient.java:115)
    at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractQueryApi$1.onResponse(AbstractQueryApi.java:228)
    at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractQueryApi.query(AbstractQueryApi.java:255)
    at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractQueryApi.query(AbstractQueryApi.java:207)
    at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractQueryApi.query(AbstractQueryApi.java:131)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.QueryApiImpl.query(QueryApiImpl.java:939)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.QueryApiImpl.query(QueryApiImpl.java:123)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.QueryApiImpl.query(QueryApiImpl.java:85)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.QueryApiImpl.query(QueryApiImpl.java:75)
    at org.atg.bems.service.InfluxService.readElectricityData(InfluxService.java:73)
    at org.atg.bems.controller.InfluxController.getElectricityData(InfluxController.java:59)
    at org.atg.bems.connection.InfluxServiceTest.readData(InfluxServiceTest.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)


most likely its something with credentials or configuration. try to see if you can connect to your InfluxDB instance via CLI or direct HTTP APIs.
